# angular material md-country-select not binding with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, triangular

I am using angular material and [md-country-select](https://github.com/ayush-bhandari/mdCountrySelect) for countries dropdown but it is not binding with ng-model.

```
<md-country-select ng-model="user.country"></md-country-select>
```

Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong.

I already used [ng-country-select](https://github.com/navinpeiris/ng-country-select) and it is working great but I need md-country-select because of some design dependencies with angular material. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Can you add a `Plunkr`, `CodePen`, ... ?

Comment: here is the link
https://plnkr.co/edit/QdV3ZeEhK3aP16JfWF2S?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

This directive uses controller as syntax, so you should be able to retrieve the selected country using something like this:

```
<md-country-select></md-country-select>
<md-card>
     {{vm.country.name}}
</md-card>
```

In your controller you can use `$watch`:

```
 $scope.$watch('vm.country', function(val) {
    console.log(val); // returns object: {code: "AS", name: "American Samoa"}
 });
```

I actually cannot find any documentation on this directive, but I have created a quick [**demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evbexx). Perhaps someone else knows of better way to acheive this...